# How do I apply CSS rules on Laravel 8's mail template?

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-mail

I am trying to create an email that is sent to customers after they place an order. I am using Laravel 8 and installed it using the command: `php artisan make:mail OrderPlaced` - this created all the necessary files. I then used: `php artisan vendor:publish` and published all the mail `blade.php` files:

[image: Vendor Files]

This is my routes file, it is sent up so I can quickly design what my email will look like without continually sending emails:

```php
/* Test email route */
Route::get('/mailable', function () {
   $order = \App\Models\Order::find(1);
   return new \App\Mail\OrderPlaced($order);
});
```

This is my `OrderPlaced.php` Mail controller:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.orders.placed')
        ->to($this->order->billing_email, $this->order->billing_name)
        ->subject($this->order->billing_name . "'s Order");
}
```

My issue is that I am trying to apply CSS to my `placed.blade.php` file. It current looks like this:

```
@component('mail::message')
    <h1>Order Received</h1>

    <p>Thank you for ordering with Mobile Mastery and we are so hyped that you decided to make us part of upgrading
    your gaming experience. Your order is being prepared and shipped currently, but in the mean time do NOT delete
    this email as you may need it, for example, to return an item. You order details are as follows:</p>

    -- OTHER ORDER RELATED STUFF --

@endcomponent
```

You can see that the title has a `<h1>` tags and the info has `<p>` tags but in the actual email, only the `<h1>` tag is applied and the `<p>` is shown on screen:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to style Laravel's `@component('mail::message')` effectively or point me to a good page for it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the data is escaped. You can see that the mail message blade has this

```
{{-- Body --}}
{{ $slot }}
```

Explanation from doc:
By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

`Hello, {!! $name !!}`

Read more
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: @RC07JNR apology, miss out the bottom part of your description. Updated my answer.